# Mysql "complex" sort

Tags: mysql, sorting

Imagine that you have 2 tables like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM theme;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | name    | sort_order |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | Theme 1 | 1          |
|  2 | Theme 2 | 2          |
|  3 | Theme 3 | 3          |
|  4 | Theme 4 | 4          |
|  5 | Theme 5 | 5          |
|  6 | Theme 6 | 6          |
|  7 | Theme 7 | 7          |
+----+---------+------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM article;
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+
| id | title      | update_date         | theme_id |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 | Article 1  | 2012-06-29 15:29:50 |        6 |
|  2 | Article 2  | 2012-07-18 00:00:00 |        2 |
|  3 | Article 3  | 2012-07-19 00:00:00 |        4 |
|  4 | Article 4  | 2012-07-18 00:00:00 |        4 |
|  5 | Article 5  | 2012-07-18 00:00:00 |        1 |
|  6 | Article 6  | 2012-06-26 10:30:51 |        6 |
|  7 | Article 7  | 2012-07-18 15:17:08 |        6 |
|  8 | Article 8  | 2012-06-18 00:00:00 |        4 |
|  9 | Article 9  | 2012-07-18 15:48:28 |        1 |
| 10 | Article 10 | 2012-07-09 00:00:00 |        4 |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Each article is bound to one-and-only-one theme.

You want to be able to execute a query that gives you a list of article ordered like this:

- the first most recent article for each theme ordered by theme's `sort_order`
- the second most recent article for each theme ordered by theme's `sort_order`
- the third most recent article for each theme ordered by theme's `sort_order`
- and so on...

For the current data, it should give the following:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+
| id | title      | update_date         | theme_id |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+
|  9 | Article 9  | 2012-07-18 15:48:28 |        1 |
|  2 | Article 2  | 2012-07-18 00:00:00 |        2 |
|  3 | Article 3  | 2012-07-19 00:00:00 |        4 |
|  7 | Article 7  | 2012-07-18 15:17:08 |        6 |
|  5 | Article 5  | 2012-07-18 00:00:00 |        1 |
|  4 | Article 4  | 2012-07-18 00:00:00 |        4 |
|  1 | Article 1  | 2012-06-29 15:29:50 |        6 |
| 10 | Article 10 | 2012-07-09 00:00:00 |        4 |
|  6 | Article 6  | 2012-06-26 10:30:51 |        6 |
|  8 | Article 8  | 2012-06-18 00:00:00 |        4 |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+
```

I'm almost sure there is a way to do this using a single query but I can't figure it out.

How would you achieve this ?

Comment: Create separate queries for each of your needed case and put them all together with [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)

Comment: @Laimoncijus: There is only one case: most recent article for each theme (if any) then second most recent article for each theme (if any) and so on...

Comment: Maybe this could help you -> http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/209784

Comment: @Panagiotis: Interesting but it doesn't help me.

Comment: I think you have to try unions then. I don't know the exact sql, I need to test the data on my db.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to the problem of partitioned ranking in MySQL. There are no windowed ranking functions in MySQL, but the generic problem can successfully be solved with the help of variables:

```
SELECT
  id,
  title,
  update_date,
  theme_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    @rnk := @rnk * (@last_theme = theme_id) + 1 AS rnk,
    @last_theme := theme_id
  FROM article, (SELECT @rnk := 0, @last_theme := 0) s
  ORDER BY theme_id, update_date DESC
) s
ORDER BY
  rnk, theme_id
;
```

The above query both ranks the rows and then uses the rankings to sort the final result set. The query first retrieves rows from `article` ordering them by `theme_id` and `update_date DESC` to assign ranking numbers. Then, when selecting from the ranked row set, another, final, ordering is introduced, this time by the rankings and `theme_id`.

You can try this query [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d568f/6).

Answer (score 0):

Could you do a 'article join theme' and then order by update_date, sort_order?

Comment: No because in this case I will get all the recent articles first regardless of the theme.